# Codenameone How to detect if device in on wifi or cellular?

Tags: codenameone

How can I detect if device is connected to wifi or cellular network ?

I need to warn users of large uploads when they are not on wifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `Connectivity` cn1lib in the extension manager. It's available here as well: https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/codenameone-connectivity